# Turning repeated row labels into column headers in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a questionnaire in this format

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Question': ['Name', 'Age', 'Income','Name', 'Age', 'Income'], 
                   'Answer': ['Bob', 50, 42000, 'Michelle', 42, 62000]})
```

As you can see the same 'Question' appears repeatedly, and I need to reformat this so that the result is as follows

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Bob', 'Michelle'], 
                   'Age': [ 50, 42],
                   'Income': [42000,62000]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `numpy.reshape`:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(df["Answer"].to_numpy().reshape((2,-1)), columns=df["Question"][:3]))
```

Or transpose and `pd.concat`:

```
s = df.set_index("Question").T

print (pd.concat([s.iloc[:, n:n+3] for n in range(0, len(s.columns), 3)]).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Both yield the same result:

```
Question      Name Age Income
0              Bob  50  42000
1         Michelle  42  62000
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You can create new column `group` with `.assign` that utilizes `.groupby` and `.cumcount` (Bob would be the first group and Michelle would be in the second group, with the groups being determined based off repetition of `Name`, `Age`, and `Income`)
2. Then `.pivot` the datraframe with the index being the `group`.

code:

```
df3 = (df.assign(group=df.groupby('Question').cumcount())
   .pivot(index='group', values='Answer', columns='Question')
   .reset_index(drop=True)[['Name','Age','Income']]) #[['Name','Age','Income']] at the end reorders the columns.
df3

Out[76]: 
Question      Name Age Income
0              Bob  50  42000
1         Michelle  42  62000
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution! It assumes that there are an even number of potential names for each observation (3 columns for Bob and  Michelle, respectively):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Question': ['Name', 'Age', 'Income','Name', 'Age', 'Income'], 
                   'Answer': ['Bob', 50, 42000, 'Michelle', 42, 62000]})

df=df.set_index("Question")
pd.concat([df.iloc[i:i+3,:].transpose() for i in range(0,len(df),3)],axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
```